# basic nested routes in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router, ember-model

I have this router

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about', function() {
        this.route('new');
    });
});
```

and

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about/new">
    <h1>About/New Page</h1>
</script>
```

However when I go to `about/new` route, I see the `about` template only. So, how do I render the template of a nested route?

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C4gSE/

Comment: I have answered your question, but this seen to be a bug. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the `data-template-name` from `about` to `about/index`.
And the `linkTo` from `about` to `about.index`

[Like this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/fsP44/)

Comment: okay! Also, one more thing, when I click on `about/new` both the `about` and `about.new` parts are 'active'. I mean, look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fsP44/2/  Does that mean that `AboutNewController` will have all the properties of `AboutIndexController`?

Comment: Use `linkTo 'about.index'`. Like this example http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/fsP44/3/

Answer (score 0):

The **outlet** helper is missing in **about** template.
It should be

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    <h2>About</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```